# It is giving me and I dont know how to fix the subquery

Tags: sql, oracle

```
SELECT
    ht.ht_nbr,
    ht_name,
    count(h.ht_nbr) AS number_of_helicopters

FROM
    MH.helicopter_type ht JOIN MH.helicopter h ON ht.ht_nbr = h.ht_nbr
    
WHERE
    h.ht_nbr = (SELECT h.ht_nbr FROM MH.helicopter WHERE count(h.ht_nbr) >= 2)


ORDER BY
    count(h.ht_nbr) DESC;
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?  Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: For each helicopter type for which there are at least two helicopters of that type, list the total
number of helicopters of that type

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
;WITH HelicopterCount   AS
    (
        SELECT 
                ht.ht_nbr
            ,   ht_name
            ,   count(h.ht_nbr) AS number_of_helicopters

        FROM    MH.helicopter_type  ht 
        JOIN    MH.helicopter       h   ON ht.ht_nbr    =   h.ht_nbr
        GROUP BY
                ht.ht_nbr
            ,   ht_name
    )

SELECT  *
FROM    HelicopterCount
WHERE   number_of_helicopters   >=  2
ORDER BY 
        number_of_helicopters DESC
;
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want a `having` clause.  Something like this:

```
SELECT ht.ht_nbr, ht.ht_name,
       COUNT(*) AS number_of_helicopters
FROM MH.helicopter_type ht JOIN    ​
     ​MH.helicopter h 
     ON ht.ht_nbr = h.ht_nbr
​GROUP BY ht.ht_nbr, ht.ht_name
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC;
```